# Does the series of cosine converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the series of cosine

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos (\pi n)}{n}$$

converge or diverge?

Answer (score 13):

It's an alternating series where the numerator is $-1$ or $1$. Denominator is linear increasing. It meets the prereqs to be conditionally convergent.

Comment: +1 on your answer. For fun what if $\pi$ is replaced by $x \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Consider $$\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\frac{e^{inx}}{n}$$ and Dirichlet's criterion.

Answer (score 6):

The series converges, in fact we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos\pi n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=-\ln2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It converges.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(\pi n\right) }{n}
 =-\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\left(-1\right)^k \frac{1}{k} 
 = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n}
 =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}\right) $$
By Integral test for convergence:

$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} f(n)$ converges if $\int_{N}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges.

$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} f(n)$ diverges if $\int_{N}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ diverges.

$$ \int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{2x-1}\right)dx=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{2x}{2x-1}\right|\bigg|_1^\infty=\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln{2}-\ln{1}\right)=\frac{\ln 2}{2}$$

The series converges because the integral converges. You can check other convergences test like the d'Alamber test.

Comment: Alan, where does this argument break when applied to $\sum(-1)^n$?

Comment: @JonathanY. We know that $(-1)^x=\left(e^{i\pi}\right)^x = e^{i\pi x} = \frac{1}{2} (\cos(\pi x)+i \sin{\pi x})$. If we integrate that last expression between $[a,\infty]$ we'll find the integral does not converge: After you integrate you'll have something like $\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty} \sin (u)$ wich is "i don't know but it may be between -1 and 1 :p". If you see (or imagine) the graphic of $\cos(x)+i \sin(x)$ when $x$ is growing, you may see that both real and imaginary part are always oscilating between -1 and 1, so, because they both not converge, the integral does not converge.

Comment: I was aiming at the first step of your answer, where you grouped the coefficients in groups of two, as in $1-1+1-1+\ldots = (1-1)+(1-1)+\ldots$. The point is that this sort of acrobatics is only justified when the series converges *absolutely*, which this one unfortunately doesn't.

Comment: @JonathanY. Oh, you have a point. So I may apply Leibniz's test for alternating series: Consider $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k a_k$. If ${a_k}$ decreases monotonically and goes to $0$ in the limit then the alternating series converges. So $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\cos{\pi k}}{k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\cos{\pi k}-1+1}{k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{\cos{\pi k}-1}{k}+\frac{1}{k}\right)=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\left(\pi\frac{\cos{\pi k}-1}{\pi k}+\frac{1}{k}\right)=0$$

Comment: I'm not sure how breaking it this way helps, but I agree that it's a (very famous) Leibniz series (as @imranfat mentioned as well).